# Instantiate and use a MembershipProvider in a standalone fashion

Tags: c#, membership-provider

My work has multiple applications with their own MembershipProviders; we use 3 different ones in about a dozen web applications.  So I had this brilliant idea that I would create an app that centrally managed the identities and roles by instantiating each provider individually in a single application.

I created a container for MembershipProviders, and made a custom config section with all the parameter information and class definitions.  I was able to instantiate the classes just fine, and run the `Initialize()` with a `NameValueCollection` of the parameters.  All this seemed to go swimmingly.

The first time I tried to invoke `GetAllUsers()` on one of the providers, though, I got the followng error:

```
The membership provider name specified is invalid.
Parameter name: providerName
```

The name is provided; I'm scratching my head on how to get around this.  Can someone offer me any help?

Comment: Did you register you provider correctly inside web.config?

Comment: Can you post you membership registration sections from web.config?

Comment: The whole point is I don't want to register the providers.  I want them standalone, working as just another class.

Comment: I think you will have to register your custom provider for this to work properly. Inside your provider you will then handle other providers.

Comment: This makes me sad.  What is the point of requiring registration in web.config to use the class?

Comment: .net can use only one membership provider at runtime. However you can register multiple providers and select them at runtime but this is what you dont want... So the only option is to implement custom membership provider, register it and than use to dynamicly to handle multiple providers at runtime.

Comment: I don't want to use it like a membership provider; I just want to access the methods and properties.  Why would anyone make this model so inflexible that you could not instantiate a public class inheriting from a public abstract `MembershipProvider` in code and access its methods?  That is unfathomable to me.